# Get more than 10 accounts in the truffle develop blockchain?

Tags: truffle, truffle-develop

How do we get more than 10 accounts in the truffle develop blockchain ?
If someone has an idea about the question in the title, would be of help to many people out there for testing.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation for [Truffle Develop](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/using-truffle-develop-and-the-console#truffle-develop):

> Note: The mnemonic and addresses cannot be changed. If you want to use
>   a different mnemonic or set of addresses, we recommend using Ganache.

If you're using Ganache, you can change the number of addresses using the "Total accounts to generate" option under the "Accounts and Keys" settings.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, the docs are out of date!

You can configure this [now](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases#user-content-what-s-new-in-truffle-v5-truffle-console-truffle-develop-configure-truffle-develop):

```
module.exports = {
  /* ... rest of config */

  networks: {
    /* ... other networks */

    "develop": {
      accounts: 5,
      defaultEtherBalance: 500,
      blockTime: 3
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the simplest way is to execute inside the console:

```
web3.personal.newAccount()
```

You can then confirm the account has been added by typing

```
web3.eth.accounts.length
```